# Can I use only itemReader of spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to implement a `customItemReader` which will extend spring batch `ItemReader` and my `customItemReader` should return list of items read from file. Now I want to process this list into my java class. Is it possible ? As I would not be initiating spring batch job. I just want to use `itemReader` to read my file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will share my understanding.. In spring batch, there are two approaches:

1) Chunk based- In Chunk based, it is mandatory to specify ItemReader and ItemWriter. You can specify Custom ItemReader and use No-op ItemWriter to basically do nothing like:

```
public class NoOpItemWriter implements ItemWriter {
void write() 
{
    // no-op
}
}
```

2) Tasklet based- In this, You can use your custom class to implement Tasklet and do the reading as you want.

Ideally within the tasklet you may be able to implement ItemReader (if required and use interface) but I havent tried it personally ever so not sure.

Comment: Actually I do not want to use spring batch job.. I want to implement my custom class which will extend itemReader. Then this class will read file using itemReader functions and list of items will be returned to calling class. It can be achieved ?

Comment: ItemReader is an interface (that is read method is not implemented..). you can implement (not extend). But I do not see any use to inherit unimplemented read method (other than Spring batch framework which will provide a flow from read to processor/writer class). Just create your .class and write code to read file..

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you please tell me one more thing I have to process a file.. I want to know what will be the difference in processing if I will set isQuoteCharacter() to false for class DelimitedLineTokenizer in spring batch.

Comment: isQuoteCharacter(char c) will take an argument as char and return true or false. you can send char to isQuoteCharacter but not set it to true/flase..Or if you are trying to ask something different create a question and give more details..

Comment: If I override isQuoteCharacter method and return false then there will be impact ?